# Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools with JAVA_HOME correctly set

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I have the following error building my android project on Ubuntu from the command line using the gradle wrapper. Running from Android Studio is fine. After some reading of other posts I'm still not sure how to fix it, since my JAVA_HOME enviroment variable is correct. I'm not setting it from any user config files but it seems to be set from somewhere on my system. I've also tried uninstall/reinstall.

```
Execution failed for task 
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
```

So where is JAVA_HOME set to and where is it installed?

```
user@user$ java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)
user@user$ echo $JAVA_HOME
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
user@user
    sudo update-java-alternatives --list
    java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

At this point I'm lost and confused.

```
user@user$ readlink -f $(which java) 
    /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
user@user$ which java
    /usr/bin/java
user@user$ whereis java
    java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

JAVA_HOME isn't set in any of my user config files, the following returns nothing

```
grep JAVA_HOME /etc/environment /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile.d/* /etc/profile
```

The only environment entries are

```
user@user$ grep -r JAVA_HOME /etc
    /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore:        export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/$jvm
    /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore:        PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Could you clarify what tool you're using to build your project and where the errors are coming from - IDE or command line?